# jQuery Mobile Partial Render - specify Ajax container

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, yii

I am using jQuery Mobile with Yii Framework.

Yii framework allows easy partial render for Ajax requests.

jQuery Mobile on the other hand will not display anything that is not within the data-role="page" container.  Even though it does an Ajax request, a full page refresh ensues because it appears to only be able to refresh all the content within this container (what's the point???).

How can I specify the container that jQuery Mobile will refresh, rather than the container with `data-role="page"`?

One would EXPECT that the container flagged with `data-role="content"` would be the Ajax container, but it's not.  I can see a JS hack coming on.

Answer (score 0):

The above can be done like this:

Create your header outside the container flagged as data-role="page".

Use the following jQuery to initialise the header (otherwise you will not see it):

```
    $(function(){
        $( "[data-role='header']" ).toolbar();
    });
```